# Trouble understanding named semaphore initialization

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I need to share a ressource between threads using named semaphores. I have a main thread, and X subthreads.

Do I have to use `sem_open` with the `O_CREAT` flag in my main thread, and then call `sem_open` again in every subthreads, with the same name but without flags?

Or do I only have to call `sem_open` once in my main thread and then use it's return value in all subthreads?

I tried both but I didn't get anything close to expected behaviour...

Comment: You can go with unnamed semaphore, that are just shared between threads; see `sem_init`.

Comment: I know I should use them but it's a school project, for which using named semaphores is mandatory

Comment: The latter, but just knowing that won't help you.  Please show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are encountering.

Comment: The normal use-case for named semaphores would be between different _processes._ In that case, each process would independently open the semaphore, and each would have its own separate handle. Are you certain that the instructor wants you to use multiple threads within a single process?

Comment: We have to do the same program twice, one with different processes, the other within the same process but with different threads. We have to use named semaphores for both of them

Comment: I made it work using the latter but my problem was not here, should I delete the post or accept any answer including mine, telling that the good one is the latter?

Answer (score 0):

You must use wait and signal functions in your threads after open your semaphore:

> The sem_open(3) function creates a new named semaphore or
> opens an existing named semaphore.  After the semaphore has
> been opened, it can be operated on using sem_post(3) and
> sem_wait(3).  When a process has finished using the semaphore,
> it can use sem_close(3) to close the semaphore.  When all
> processes have finished using the semaphore, it can be removed
> from the system using sem_unlink(3).

Reference : [sem_overview(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

Comment: I used this man page to write my code, but why to use signal and wait ?

Comment: Semaphore are just integer values which decrease and increase atomic operation to enable you to do functions in critical sections. The initial value is 1 (or you must set) and when you call wait it convert to zero. Now another function call wait first check it be more than 0. If 0 it waits. You need call signal at the end of process to change value from 0 to 1 and other process can start.

Comment: I think you're talking about `sem_wait` and `sem_post` functions, which I already use

Comment: They have same functionality with different names! Did you call them after open in a right way?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know! Yep, my mistake wasn't here... I got it working now